# Perfect number in gaussian integers

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, complex-numbers, unique-factorization-domains, perfect-numbers

We have complete description about irreducibles in the ring Z[i],of gaussian integers. Now I was trying to define suitably the notion of "perfect number" in Z[i]. But the problem is unique factorization into irreducibles is unique upto associates. So how one should possibly try to resolve this?

Comment: With a little Googling I found this: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa25/aa2523.pdf I haven't had time to read it carefully yet.

Comment: The paper [On the Form of Odd Perfect Gaussian Integers](http://ajmonline.org/2008/6.pdf) by Matthew Ward might be of some interest to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the integers you don't mix positive and negative factors. Why not pick the/a sum of factors with the maximum modulus which would be compatible with the usual definition for integers.

Comment: but if we multiply i with every factor and the modulus will remain same.For example |a+b| and modulus of |ia+ib| are same

Comment: @SAUVIK That's fine - in the integers we'd get negative perfect numbers. But you have a finite number of options, and if any of them is equal to your original number you could call it perfect, After all mutiplying the original number by $i$ gives a number with the same prime factorisation up to associates.